# Kaa - Cassandra Log Appender

Tags: kaa

If my logged message (log schema) has nested structures ,how to use the cassandra log appender provided by Kaa (Kaa log appender UI console) to map the nested field values to the cassandra columns ?

Answer (score 0):

Current implementation of cassandra log appender doesn't allow to map nested fields. We have the [ticket](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/CASSAP-9) about improving the log appender and will implement it in the next KAA version.

If you aren't able to wait until the next Kaa release, we suggest you look at [attempt](https://github.com/Acarus/kaa/blob/develop/server/appenders/cassandra-appender/src/main/java/org/kaaproject/kaa/server/appenders/cassandra/appender/CassandraLogEventDao.java#L530) to implement such functionality.